# PHPで日付をEPOCHにする

Tags: php

こんにちは

こんにちは

下記の日付をEPOCHにしたいですが

```
土曜日, 11月 5, 2016, 01:36 AM
```

どうすればよいでしょうか。方法を教えていただければとありがたいです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: date_create_from_format() を使ってもよいかと。`$date = date_create_from_format('*, n月 j, Y, h:i A', $string); echo date_format($date, 'U');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問の日付形式を直接strtotimeに食べさせても理解してくれないので、正規表現で整形してあげると良いのではないでしょうか。

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
$string = '土曜日, 11月 5, 2016, 01:36 AM';
$pattern = '/.+?, *(\d{1,2})月 *(\d{1,2}), *(\d{1,4}), *(.+)/i';
$replacement = '$3/$1/$2 $4';
$strdate = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
echo strtotime($strdate);
?>
```

Comment: 丁寧な回答をどうもありがとうございます。